# Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat for Flask Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to load a Flask app in a subdirectory on my domain. Below is my virtual host configuration. the Flask app is kept at /var/www/FlaskApps/Recommender/

[image: My Virtual host config]

Apache's error log keeps saying "Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/FlaskApps/FlaskApp.wsgi" when i try to reach the endpoint /recommender

From online other people said it might be a permission issue, but I'm not sure if it's the case per snapshot below.

Thanks for your help

[image: My .wsgi file permission]

Comment: Please include the actual code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `FlaskApps.wsgi` in directory, but `FlaskApp.wsgi` in `WSGIScriptAlias` directive. So they don't match.